# ajax window while executing code in the background asp.net

Tags: asp.net, ajax, visual-studio-2010

I have a three pages form in which I need to collect data.
While transferring from one page to another I would like to display ajax window which will say, for example, "saving your data", and while that is shown on the screen I would like to run a code in the background?

Answer (score 0):

Try this way.

While saving data call the ajax model popup on the click event and initialize the thread in the init event of popup window and once the work is done, close the popup window.
Model Popup will also disable the other control on the page using background css.

```
    public void SimpleWork()
{

    //Do something

}
 Now you use either this method 

 ThreadStart operation = new ThreadStart(SimpleWork);

 Thread theThread = new Thread(Operation);

 theThread.Start();
 or

 ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(delegate{SimpleWork();});
```

If you find it useful, Mark it as your answer else let me know..